# On trying to verify digits user on Server I am getting error code 32 “Could not authenticate you”

Tags: twitter-oauth, twitter-fabric

The server side verification is  failing for me with code 32 and message "Could not authenticate you.". I have an android app where i am using digits to authenticate users using their mobile number. Inside the success callback, i follow the oauth echo tutorial and use the consumer key and secret along with auth token and secret obtained from digit session to generate an oauth signature(X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization) as well get the url to hit to verify credentials(X-Auth-Service-Provider) on the backend. I then try to do a curl request by plugging the oauth signature into Authorization header for the request as indicated in the tutorial. However i get error code 32 - could not authenticate you. Have tried with multiple numbers without any success. It would be great if anyone could indicate what i am doing wrong or provide any help in fixing this. Without this fix, i am afraid i would have to use my exisiting OTP architecture and won't be able to take advantage of this fantastic library.

Comment: Did you find a solutionn for this ?

Comment: did you find anything ?? please reply must